# JQuery Load callback function always returns 'success'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having difficulty with the .load jQuery function and it is very frustrating because it seems like this should be working.  I am attempting to load html content into a div.  When the url parameter is set to a file that exists on my server, it works fine, meaning the div is loaded with the content. 
However, if I intentionally set the url parameter to a file that does not exist on my server, as shown below, it still returns as 'Content Loaded Successfully'.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var divaboutMe = $('#aboutMe');
    var url = "dave.txt";
    divaboutMe.load(url, function (responseText, statusText, xhr)
        {
            if (statusText == "error")
                {
                    alert('Error Loading Content')
                }
            else
                {
                    alert('Content Loaded Successfully')
                }
        });

});
```

I searched Stack Exchange for this issue but could not find any other posts that were exactly related.  I would like to know why this does not work to further my understanding of jQuery/Javascript.

Edit #1:
As suggested I have modified my code to display the actual values of statusText and on a whim added an alert for xhr.StatusText, although I do not really know what that does.  I also removed the 'divaboutMe' variable and am using the jQuery id selector.  After these updates I am still getting the same results which is quite maddening.  I have seen this code in numerous websites and in a couple of my own books so I do not know what could possibly be wrong.

Here is the updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var url = "8";
    $('#aboutMe').load(url, function (responseText, statusText, xhr)
    {
        alert('statusText: ' + xhr.statusText)

        if (statusText === "error")
            {
                alert('Error Loading Content:' + statusText)
            }
        else
            {
                alert('Content Loaded Successfully:' + statusText)
            }
    });

});
```

Comment: Comes back with "Error loading Content" for me.

Comment: what is `statusText` when you point it to a non existing file? It could be another error message like Keith says, which is not equal to "error", thus your else clause is triggered.

Comment: Hello, statusText is always returning 'success'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I found the issue, but the solution brings up a bigger problem.  My Website is hosted on my own personal web-server which has a LAMP Stack using the latest version of Ubuntu.  In my websites root folder I have a .htacces file which contains a redirection rule that sends requests for files that do not exist back to index.php.  I disabled the .htacess file and sure enough the code started returning 'error' when attempting to load a file that does not exist on my server.  So, not sure what to do next but wanted to post in case anyone else has come across this type of behavior and has any suggestions.  Here is the contents of my .htaccess file:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1